# handling a json base64 encode image from iphone app with php

Tags: php, ios, json, rest, base64

I am working on a php REST API that will be used with an iPhone app. It is another developer who develops the app.
From that app it is possible to take a image and upload it to the webserver. I will recieve the images from the iphone as base64 with json, but I am unsure how to process them with a PHP script.
The images will be send like:

```
{
"image1":"Base64Data",
"image2":"Base64Data",
"image3":"Base64Data",
"image4":"Base64Data"
}
```

will it be something like:

```
$image1 = json_decode($jsonData);
```

Is it possible to get the same / a like data from the base64 string as from `$_FILES[]` upload? When images a upload the normal way from the website, they are being handled with a cropper and thumbnail generator. I want the base64 images to be handled the same way.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As far as the bas64 encoded images goes. You can display them with CSS and or javascript. If you are going to do some processing on them you probably need something like GD or IMagick

Comment: @Morten Hagh-   userimage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:responseString]]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json which looks like this

```
{
"image1":"Base64Data",
"image2":"Base64Data",
"image3":"Base64Data",
"image4":"Base64Data"
}
```

will not be  something like:

```
$image1 = json_decode($jsonData);
```

more like this

```
$json = json_decode($jsonData, true);
$image1 = $json['image1'];
```

There will be no values similar to `$_FILES` except the data of the file.

you can easily do

```
$imagedata = base64_decode($image1);
file_put_contents("file.jpg", $imagedata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decode Base64 encoded, with this: base64_decode($yourstring)

Also, you can decode the Json and after the Base 64 encoded.